# Is there a general term for typefaces which emulate degraded, imperfect, or worn letterpress type?

Tags: typography

An example of a font like this:

[image: example of this kind of typeface]

Note the non-contiguous "w" and irregularity in the outline of all the letters (particularly noticeable in the "o" and "p"). I assume the effect here is trying to emulate letter press techniques where the surface of the type isn't perfectly flat or imprecisely machined.

I'm looking for a term that describes these sorts of typefaces, if there is one, or just a more concise way of describing it.

Comment: Not a great question in my opinion, but... your choice of an adjective is as good as anyone else's choice.... **Distressed** or worn perhaps.  I believe that disconnected `w` is actually part of the typeface. Garamond (which is the typeface) has such a broad and sweeping poole of different versions from different foundries, it's hard to say what *specific* flavor of Garamond *that* Garamond may be.